# RegEx with any number replace by empty string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am totally not confirm with Regular Expressions, so may you guys can help me out.

I have a String like "blablabla_300x300.jpg" where 300 can be any number
I need to replace the "_300x300" with ""

Can please someone provide me the correct answer (Javascript)
Thank you so much

Comment: If you don't demonstrate your efforts on solving the issue, this is going to be off-topic.

Comment: What about `_\d+x\d+(?=\.)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var s = "blablabla_300x300.jpg";
s = s.replace(/(_\d+x\d+)(\.jpg)$/, "$2");
console.log(s);
```

Comment: Thanks, i changed it to s.replace(/\_(\d)+x(\d)+/, '') which does the job perfectly. Thank you so much

Comment: @PeterLakatos-appnomads you can simply use `_(\d+)x\d+(?=\.)` with `$1` as replacement.